# Ошибка ORA-02054 при работе через dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Столкнулся с проблемой, объяснить которую не могу. Суть:

1. В цикле вызываю функцию, которая запускает функцию в другой базе данных через dblink

   a:= some_scheme.some_package.some_function@some_dblink(some_parameter);
2. Функция сохраняет параметр в той базе данных, а возвращает ключ, под которым этот параметр сохранил. Но при использовании выпрыгивает эта ошибка:

   ORA-02054: транзакция 13.25.67372 в неопр.состоянии

Не понимаю её природы и гугл не спас.

Comment: И часто ошибка выскакивает?  Если вы так вызываете функцию, как указали, без имени функции, то должна быть другая ошибка.

Comment: @0xdb ваша правда, не указал функцию. Ошибка выскакивает при любой попытке обращения к функции через линк. Если другая схема лежит в моей же базе (и линк не нужен), то всё отрабатывает корректно без этой ошибки.

Comment: Попробуйте создать линк на той же базе и машине: `create database link loopback using 'orasid';` . Будет с ним работать?

Comment: Уф, чуть не забыл. Не в момент обращения к функции, а именно в момент коммита. Можно миллион раз к ней обратиться или один раз, а ошибка брякнется в момент коммита.

Comment: Попробовал воспроизвести вашу задачу, но всё работает. Добавте по возможности в вопрос  минимальный воиспроизводимый пример.